Import issue (python 3.11)
lets say i have the following structure
(Project 1 = name)
Project1/
    __init__.py
    constants.py
    subfolder1/
         Algorithm.py
         More Processes reuqired for Algorithm...

if i try to 'from .. import constants', i get  either(depending on what i use) "ModuleNotFoundError" or "ImportError" where the parent package is not found.
i tried to add Project1 to path and added an init.py file as well but nothing changed.
What could be the source of the issue and how can i fix this?
I have tried using all these but nothing works.
from . import constants
from .. import constants 
from ... import constants
from .constants import *
from ..constants import *
from ...constants import *

I also did these:
reinstall python,
fallback to version 3.10
add to path
try on a different project
Im getting desperate on what could be wrong

I have tried using all these but nothing works Where, exactly, did you try those?  In Algorithm.py ?

Algorithm.py , start of code to be clear.

How, exactly, did you run the code?  What was the exact command?

i just ran it on vscode and i didnt bother running it on cmd prompt because it didnt work on vscode. sorry for the late reply i was eating
